# Repeat Region inside another one

Tags: php, mysql, repeat, region

So im trying this but it doesnt work and i cant figured it out why.

Code:

```
<?php do { ?>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
<?php echo $row_hoteleiro['id_hoteleiro']; ?>
<br />
<select name="id_categorias">
<?php do {  ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_categorias['id_categorias']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_categorias['id_categorias'], htmlentities($row_hoteleiro['id_categorias'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>><?php echo $row_categorias['categorias']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_categorias = mysql_fetch_assoc($categorias));
?>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_hoteleiro['nome'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="rua" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_hoteleiro['rua'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="codigopostal" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_hoteleiro['codigopostal'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="cidade" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_hoteleiro['cidade'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_hoteleiro['date'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Update record" />

<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
<input type="hidden" name="id_hoteleiro" value="<?php echo $row_hoteleiro['id_hoteleiro']; ?>" />
</form>
<?php } while ($row_hoteleiro = mysql_fetch_assoc($hoteleiro)); ?>
```

So the real problem is here:

```
<select name="id_categorias">
<?php do {  ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_categorias['id_categorias']?>" <?php if (!(strcmp($row_categorias['id_categorias'], htmlentities($row_hoteleiro['id_categorias'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>><?php echo $row_categorias['categorias']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_categorias = mysql_fetch_assoc($categorias));
?>
</select>
```

Im trying to repeat region inside a repeated region already, and that might be the problem, because when i test the code it loops all the records but on the selected option it only shows at the first result on the others is full blank.

I already tried to get the error on google but couldnt find anything,

Cumps.

[image: Results Blank]

Comment: done already add the image at the main post.